# Mars helicopter ingenuity stress testing at end of mission?

Tags: perseverance, ingenuity

Ingenuity is mainly a [proof-of-concept](https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/#Quick-Facts) to the main Perseverence mission. It worked very well considering the challanges. When the helicopter is done being "useful", will it be stress-tested with i.e. faster/longer flights, more difficult terrain, etc to see how much it can take before crashing?

Comment: Flying [is becoming harder because of seasonal changes in the atmosphere](https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/status/334/flying-on-mars-is-getting-harder-and-harder/), so yes, in a way the upcoming flights will be beyond the range that it was tested for on earth. But they will try this out in tiny steps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In some sense, it already *is*.

Ingenuity was designed for 5 short test hops during the first 30 days. Pretty much every flight since then was higher, farther, and longer than originally designed and planned, in addition to the helicopter only being planned to operate for 5 flights and only for 30 days.

> When the helicopter is done being "useful"

It was actually never planned to be "useful". Even the scouting missions it has done recently are already outside of its design criteria. So, the "useful" flights, as you call them, already *are* stress testing in some sense.